# PHP mail () function sending email

Tags: html, function, email

Here is the trouble I'm having I have a page called contacts.html on this page I have a contact form with the following code

```
` <h2 class="top-1 p3">Contact form</h2>
        <form id="form" method="post"  action="html_form_send.php" >
          <fieldset>
            <label for="first_name"><strong>First Name:</strong><input type="text" name="first_name" value=""></label>
            <label for="last_name"><strong>Last Name:</strong><input type="text" name="last_name" value=""></label>
            <label for="email"><strong>Email:</strong><input type="text" name="email" value=""></label>
            <label for="telephone"><strong>Phone:</strong><input type="text" name="telephone" value=""></label>
            <label for="comments"><strong>Your Message:</strong><textarea></textarea></label>
<br>            <div class="btns"><a href="#" class="button">Clear</a><a href="#" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Send</a></div>`
```

This isn't the whole code just the part containing the form. I'm using GoDaddy to host and it doesn't support X-mailer. I have to use the PHP's mail( ) function. So I've been looking at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php][1]. Below is the code I have in the html_form_send.php file. The form sends this is just a template I'm not sure how to get the values (ex: first_name, last_name, comments) and write it into the php file. I tried doing $to      = $_POST['first_name']; and then using .$data['first_name'] but that didn't work. Please discard the random table info

```
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>


  [1]: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
```

Thanks!

Comment: <?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'michaelgaraysi@yahoo.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Crown Jewel email from' 

This part cut off